# If statement not working as intended

Tags: php, sql, if-statement, while-loop

Now that first one works, but it will not make it to the second one..

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rank = $row["rank"];
    if($rank == "President/Main Developer" or $rank == "Administrator/Asst. Developer")
    {   
        echo "In first while";
        echo "<td>" . $row["username"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='color: #FF4747'>" . $row["rank"] . "</td>";
        $time = formatTime($row["joinDate"]);
        echo "<td>" . $time . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `or` and `and` in PHP if statements. The correct operators are `||` for or and `&&` for and.

You also have a `;` at the end of the `if` statement which is causing problems.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rank = $row["rank"];
    if($rank == "President/Main Developer" || $rank == "Administrator/Asst. Developer")
    {   
        echo "In first while";
        echo "<td>" . $row["username"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='color: #FF4747'>" . $row["rank"] . "</td>";
        $time = formatTime($row["joinDate"]);
        echo "<td>" . $time . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

and the second bit of code:

```
while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "In second while";
    echo "<td>" . $row2["username"] . "</td>";
    if ($row["rank"]!="President/Main Developer" && $row2["rank"]!="Administrator/Asst. Developer")
    {
        echo "<td>" . $row2["rank"] . "</td>";
    }
    $time = formatTime($row2["joinDate"]);
    echo "<td>" . $time . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Also, you *may* want to use a newline character in your echos. It makes no difference to the output in a browser, but it makes it MUCH easier to read the HTML for yourself. You can do it like this:

```
echo "<td>" . $row2["rank"] . "</td>\n";
```

The only difference is when you view the code, that will have the enxt bit starting on a new line.

Edit: Re Not getting into the second loop

If you are expecting the same row to be used, you need to stick it all into a single while loop - or run the query again against your database. The while loop will fetch each row of the result one at a time until it runs out. Unless you query the database again, there simply won't be any more rows to fetch, hence it never enters the loop.

Comment: `||` has a greater precedence than `or`, `&&` has a greater precedence than `and` but using them wont break your script

Comment: Okay, that works, but why is it not making it into the second while loop?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Good god, I never even knew that. Have *always* used `||` and `&&`. Thank you! +1

Comment: I am used to Lua, which uses or and and.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you have is the ; at the end of the if sentence. When you put ; you're saying the sentence ends there, which would be like saying the "then" part of the if is empty, and then the { are irrelevant.

Here's what you want:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $rank = $row["rank"];
    if($rank == "President/Main Developer" or $rank == "Administrator/Asst. Developer")
    {   
        echo "In first while";
        echo "<td>" . $row["username"] . "</td>";
        echo "<td style='color: #FF4747'>" . $row["rank"] . "</td>";
        $time = formatTime($row["joinDate"]);
        echo "<td>" . $time . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the query itself...
the first query would be

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE `rank` = 'President/Main Developer' OR `rank` = 'Administrator/Asst. Developer'";

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE `rank` != 'President/Main Developer' OR `rank` != 'Administrator/Asst. Developer'";
```

you do the first one first, then the last one, no need for IF statements :)

Comment: Because of how the page is built, I can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

When you don't "re-query" between the two loops, you already have reached the end of your result. So the second `while`-loop got nothing to do.

You have to reset it, before going on again:

```
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
```